# Take particular value from the variable having html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

1. Below is the script which is taking the closest sibling value

   `var owner = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.select_fly').html();`
2. Following is the output of the owner variable

Now i want to take BLR from the owner variable, Can u please help this out :(

```
<p> Flight  235  <span style="margin-left:50px;">BLR</span> </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it using `find()` this way:

```
$(owner).find("span").text();
```

or directly:

```
var spanText = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.select_fly').find("span").text();
```